# what is the difference between kernel panic and software exception?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

A software interrupt, also called an exception, is an interrupt that is caused by software, usually by a program in user mode.

kernel panic is caused by Hosed updates, failing hardware, unsupported hardware, failed or missing drive or partition.

By this I came to the conclusion that software exceptions occurs in user mode and kernel panic is occurred in kernel (not sure about this conclusion).

is there any other differences between kernel panic and software exception?

Comment: Software interrupt is a very general mechanism of interrupting an execution to make something more important or to take in account something urgent. Interrupt are usually asynchronous Exception is a kind of interrupt usually used to signal an error and are synchronous to execution. All can be used in all modes of execution. Kernel panic is an "action" that is taken when something is seriously wrong in *nix kernels: stop everything, no possible recover.

Answer (score 1):

According to wikipedia [Kernel Panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic)

A kernel panic (sometimes abbreviated as KP[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_panic)), also known as computer death or PC death, is an action taken by an operating system upon detecting an internal fatal error from which it cannot safely recover. The term is largely specific to Unix and Unix-like systems; for Microsoft Windows operating systems the equivalent term is "Stop error" (resulting in a "Stop error screen," or colloquially, a "Blue Screen of Death").

According to wikipedia [Exception and how it is handled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling)

Exception handling is the process of responding to the occurrence, during computation, of exceptions – anomalous or exceptional conditions requiring special processing – often changing the normal flow of program execution. It is provided by specialized programming language constructs or computer hardware mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

To add more points to the existing answer.

> The kernel panic is Non mask able(NMI) interrupt, which kernel serves
> immediately with high priority, unlike software interrupts.
>
> More than this, we can also observe that when kernel panic happens,
> system will have to reboot to recover and restore the system running.
> However, this could not be the case, always!

So, this is how they are different from each other.

Comment: Add a source if you add an explanation.